# In provider service can we have two or more interactions with same state or providerState?

Tags: pact

In provider service can we have two or more interactions with same state or providerState.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same provider state across multiple interactions. On the consumer side, the state is simply there as a marker to say "before this interaction happens, we expect the provider to be in *this state*".

It is used on the provider side verification, to ensure the provider has the opportunity to set itself up in a known, named state (e.g. has users in the db or has no users in the db).